# jquery-confirm plugin - submit form confirmation

Tags: jquery, css

I am using this plugin - https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/
for confirming before submitting a form.
Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="">
<button name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs confirm_delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</button>
</form>
```

And my javascript:

```
$("button.confirm_delete").confirm({
    title: '',
    content: 'Please confirm you want to delete this item. This action is irreversible!',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
            this.$target.submit();
        },
        cancel: function () {

        }
    }
});
```

And upon confirmation, nothing happens. In the console I get *[button.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs.confirm_delete]* on this line: *this.$target.submit();* What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not just say $('form').submit() ?

Comment: There are other forms on the page.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this in your confirm click

```
this.$target.parent().submit()
```

> this

is the Confirm object

> $target

being your delete button

and

> parent()

being your form

here is a fiddle for you
https://jsfiddle.net/fxabnk4o/5/

**Note this will work if you have set up your HTML the way you have shown**

Comment: Okay but there are many forms with different value for the hidden input. This is refreshing the page but it doesn't seem to submit anything or at least the correct data.

Comment: Do you know why this happens? I have been banging my head with this problem for hours.

Comment: I don't know what and where you are trying to submit this form? also your hidden field doesn't show any value, are you setting the required value properly?

Comment: It's just an integer but I removed it because it's a php code.